# Bechor Shor (Ribash) on the Nachash Nechoshet (Copper Snake) of Parshat Chukas

Tags: sources-mekorot, rishonim, bamidbar-numbers-book-of, chukas

Does anyone have access to the Mossad HaRav Kook edition of Rabbi Yosef Bechor-Shor's *peirush* (commentary) on the Torah? Specifically, if anyone is able to scan and upload an image of the section(s) where he talks about the Nachash HaNechoshet, that would be great. It is Sefer Bamidbar, Perek 21. It really doesn't have to be the Mossad HaRav Kook version in particular, but I think it is better because of the super-commentary that some of their seforim have. I want to see this because my rabbi-friend pointed out to me that the Artscroll Chumash quotes the Bechor Shor here and we both wanted to "see it inside." If you help me obtain this, then you are also fulfilling the mitzvah of *Shimush Chachamim*.

Cf. [Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8)

Comment: Nope, I was getting it for my friend who is, so you would be helping him. (Unless you say that since I learn that makes me a Talmid and since I have some wisdom that makes me a Chacham.) But then you are a T"C as well. What's the big deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's online [on hebrewbooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40226&st=&pgnum=105).

Comment: +1, I didn't realize that the Ribash was the Bechor Shor. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamMosheh There's another Bechor Shor; see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/51017/5323)